# How to migrate Rails Application to different hosting provider

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, web-hosting, database-migration, mysql2

I started rails app with mysql2. First I'm going to deploy it to cheap server.When users get increased i need to migrate it to AWS or digitalocean.How to get database backup and restore it to new one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Marc's answer is good but there might be more rails way

You can use an existing gem [rails-backup-migrate](https://github.com/mattconnolly/rails-backup-migrate)

Add this to your GemFile

```
gem 'rails-backup-migrate'
```

and then do

```
bundle install
```

OR install directly

```
gem install rails-backup-migrate
```

Once this is installed you can backup your data using

```
rake site:backup
```

It creates a .tgz backup of your DB data with schema of your app.

Then to restore to some other Rails Application, move your .tgz file to the directory of your rails app and do

```
rake site:restore
```

Comment: Rails way, Great ! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL backup and restore is common. Guides can be found on virtually any google result.

General idea:

backup: # `mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql`

restore:# `mysql -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] < dumpfilename.sql`

Comment: think you meant `mysqldump` too for the restore part right ?

Comment: @FrédéricHenri Nope for restore you need to use mysql not mysqldump